# Cpp/C++ redefine operator=

Tags: c++, operators, operator-keyword, copy-constructor

I have a `class foo` with an unique `int ID` and a `string name`.
The ID is automatically assigned at construction and the name is an argument of the constructor.
The copy constructor is `=deleted`.

Now I need to reassign the operator=
so that:

`foo f1("Name1"); foo f2 = f1;`

equates to

`f2.ID =/= f1.ID`

but

`f2.Name = f1.Name`

This is the class:

```
#include <iostream>

class foo
{
private:
    static int MaxID;
    int ID;
    string Name;

public:
    foo(string l_Name):Name(l_Name),ID(MaxID) {MaxID++}
    foo(foo&) = delete;

    getName() { return Name; };
    setName(string TempName) { Name = TempName; };
};
```

This is the best I can come up with

```
foo& operator=(foo& right)
{
    this.setName(right.getName);
    return *this;
};
```

Comment: What's the expression "Cpp/C++" represent?  Is it different than C++?

Comment: Show an [mcve] rather than describing your program.  Show some facts!

Comment: Also, please explain this operator: `=/=`.

Comment: `foo f2 = f1;` is not assignment. It’s initialization. It doesn’t use `operator=`, despite the `=` sign. Back in the olden days it used the copy constructor.

Comment: If I read this correctly you either want `operator=` to assign a new id and copy the name, or just copy the name. Both seem easy enough.

Comment: That's not going to work, because `foo f2 = f1;` would not be a copy-assignment but instead an initialization, so you can't do it if your copy constructor is deleted. You could *try* doing `foo f2 = std::move(f1);` and defining an appropriate move-assignment constructor, but I would not recommend it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja The first one is what I wanna do, but I cant :(

Comment: Tactically this is dangerous because it establishes unexpected behaviour for the assignment operator. Many tools expect a particular behaviour, for example, if you put a `foo` into a `std::vector` the `ID` is going to get completely screwed up as the `vector` is resized, items are removed, inserted, and what-have-you unless you take additional steps.

Comment: This smells like XY Problem.  There's no particularly appropriate advice on solving the problem as posed because this is an anti-pattern.  Please describe what _actual_ problem you are trying to solve with this design.  There will almost certainly be a better way to do it.

Comment: @paddy I need to define the operator= to set some variables of the object the same while assigning default values to the others

Comment: No, I understand what you're trying to do, but you're missing the point.  You are only describing how you want this class to work -- you are not explaining _why_ you wrote this class to begin with...  _i.e._ what actual problem is the class being used to solve.  That is what I'm talking about.  We can happily assist you in defining a copy constructor, assignment operator, and comparison operators to make it "work".  But gut instinct says that doing so would be irresponsible.

Comment: @paddy ah, i see. This is an assignment and the literal task is "define the operator=, in a way that it only copies the base data" and i just don't know how I do it

Comment: @Finn "*i just don't know how I do it*" - yes, you do, because you showed it in your original question: `foo& operator=(foo& right) { this.setName(right.getName); return *this; }` is the right way to go for what you describe. However, `right` should be `const`, at least: `foo& operator=(const foo& right)`

Comment: @Remy Lebau so it should work? cuz if i exclude it my code runs and with it it doesnt. Is there anything special with the implementation or the location it hast to be declared?

Comment: `foo f1("Name1"); foo f2 = f1;` will not work if the copy constructor is disabled.  `foo f1("Name1"); foo f2; f2 = f1;` will work with an overridden `operator=`, but as stated earlier, this can be dangerous if you are not careful.

Comment: So the assignment itself sounds quite smelly... Just to provide some background for people's hesitance: what you're asked to do violates rules C20, C21 and C22 of the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-ctor). I would personally just write `f2.setName(f1.getName());`, and decide whether it's sensible to allow any copy semantics for this class.